# Object in array is replaced when trying to append it via prepareForSegue

Tags: swift

When I run my code, everything runs fine without errors. However, when I try to add a cell to my table view using an add button, a segue, and a text field, I am unable to do so. What happens is that when I append the object (custom) to the array that is used to create the cells, the array is emptied and filled again. The result of this is just having one cell at the table view at one time. The code is below..

Routine.swift:

```
struct Routine {

    var name: String?
    var desc: String?
}
```

RoutineListViewController.swift:

```
class RoutineListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,              UITableViewDataSource {

    var routines = [Routine]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    println("There are \(routines.count) routine(s).")

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return routines.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RoutineCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    var cellName = routines[indexPath.row].name!

    cell.textLabel?.text = cellName

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
}
```

EditRoutineViewController:

```
class EditRoutineViewController: UIViewController {

    var newRoutine = Routine(name: "", desc: "")
    var routineName: String?
    var routineDescription: String?

    var allTextFields: UITextField?

@IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var descriptionField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    allTextFields = textField

    if (textField.placeholder == "Name") {

        if (textField.text != nil) {

        routineName = textField.text
        println("Routine name set as '\(routineName)'")
        }

        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return true

    } else if (textField.placeholder == "Description") {

        if (textField.text != nil) {

        routineDescription = textField.text
        println("Routine description set as '\(routineDescription!)'")
        }

        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return true
    }

    return true
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let navController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
        let RoutineListController = navController.topViewController as RoutineListViewController

        println("There are \(RoutineListController.routines.count) routines in the routines array.")
        RoutineListController.routines.append(newRoutine)
        println("There are \(RoutineListController.routines.count) routines in the routines array.")
        println("A new routine called \(newRoutine.name!) has been added to the routines array.")
}

@IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject) {
    allTextFields?.endEditing(true)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {

    routineName = self.nameField.text
    routineDescription = self.descriptionField.text

    if (self.nameField.text == "") {

        // Display alert view
        let nameAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:
            "Make sure you enter a name for the routine", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        nameAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(nameAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {

        println("A routine called \(self.routineName!) is about to be created.")

        if (self.routineDescription != nil) {
            println("It has a description of '\(self.routineDescription!)'.")
        }

        var localRoutine = Routine(name: routineName, desc: routineDescription?)

        self.newRoutine = localRoutine

        view.endEditing(true)

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showRoutines", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd venture a guess that the problem lies in the code in `EditRoutineViewController` which saves the new routine and exits/navigates back to the `RoutineViewController` view. Namely, with this piece of code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let navController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
    let RoutineListController = navController.topViewController as RoutineListViewController

    RoutineListController.routines.append(newRoutine)
}
```

you create a **new** instance of `RoutineViewController` and push it on the navigation stack. Since `RoutineViewController` starts with an empty `Routine` array, you just add the single, newly-created item. And so on, and so on (I can't see from your code how you call the edit window from the `RoutineViewController`, but it seems it works like this).

If this is indeed the case, then you'll need to change the application flow a little bit. So, I'm presuming that the app starts from the `RoutineViewController` view, which should then modally show `EditRoutineViewController` as soon as you tap on the 'Add' or '+' button. `EditRoutineViewController` should also define a protocol (let's call it `EditRoutineDelegate`) with two methods:

```
protocol EditRoutineDelegate {
    func didSaveRoutine(routine: Routine)
    func didCancelEnteringRoutine()
}
```

You'd need to modify the routine-saving routine (*chuckle chuckle*) to something like this:

```
} else {
    var localRoutine = Routine(name: routineName, desc: routineDescription?)
    self.newRoutine = localRoutine
    view.endEditing(true)

    self.delegate.didSaveRoutine(self.newRoutine)
 }
```

So, now, when you enter a new routine in `EditRoutineViewController` it calls its delegate, `RoutineViewController` to execute the adding of the new routine and refreshing of the table view. The implementation could be something like this:

```
func didSaveRoutine(routine: Routine) {
    routines.append(routine)
    tableView.reloadData()
    navigationController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

And the `didCancelEnteringRoutine` can just dismiss the modal window.

I'd be glad to elucidate any details I failed to mention.

PS: I presume you have working knowledge on how delegation works. If not, it would be a great idea to spend some time learning about the concept, since it's a widely used pattern in Cocoa.

**EDIT:** Here's a [small demo project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/185344/StackOverflow/Routines.zip) which has the functionality you need. I hope it will be clearer this way.

Comment: I am fairly new to Swift, so I have very vague knowledge on delegates. I know that the errors I'm getting are probably a very simple fix, but since I don't understand your solution I would like your help to understand it. Here are screenshots of the errors I'm receiving:

http://imgur.com/jfgh3EV
http://imgur.com/NkWPcsR

Comment: @rodrigochousal I have added a link to a demo project which has the functionality you need. Along with my original answer, it should provide enough context.